# show array which is not 0 (ie [num] !=0)

Tags: php, zend-framework

i want to store array datas upto [num] reaches 0, once [num]=0 then i should stop storing  and start storing array after [num] != 0

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [num] => 123213
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2     
        [num] => 28349
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [num] => 456456
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2     
        [num] => 0
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [num] => 324234
    )
    [6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2     
        [num] => 5457565
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code you can store your old array to a new array avoiding all items with your criteria where ['num'] is equal to 0.

```
$oldarray = ***your own arrayname that contains your values****;

$newarray = array();
foreach ($oldarray as $a){
    if($a['num']!=0){
        array_push($newarray, $a);
    }
}
```

With the above code $newarray will store all the items according to your criteria.